# Nextjs SWR why data is not rendered on screen

Tags: next.js, swr

I have Fetcher functions. Fetcher 1 data is used in Fetcher 2. According to documentation I created 2 dependant hooks,

```
const { data: stakedByStaker } = useSWR('stakedByStaker', ()=> fetcherStakedByStaker(slice, accounts))
const { data: listStaked, error } = useSWR(()=>'listStaked'+stakedByStaker[0].staker, ()=>fetcherStakedFights(stakedByStaker, accounts, web3))

if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
if (!listStaked) return <div>loading...</div>
return (...)
```

I can see correct data from Fetcher 2 in the Console. But that data is not Rendered on screen.

Anybody can helps please?

Comment: Where are you rendering the data from the second `useSWR` call? It's not visible from the snippet you provided.

Comment: I return it in the Return ( {listStaked && listStaked....})

Comment: What's in the `listStaked` data exactly? Can you show the format of the response data you get?

Comment: this is the Fetcher which I use to fetch data:                                                     
  const fetcherStakedFights =  async(stakedByStaker, accounts, web3) =>  {
        const listN =[]
        stakedByStaker.map((f) => {
        const fight = new web3.eth.Contract(polygonFight.abi,f.fightContract)
        const adminFights =  fight.methods.staked().call({ from: accounts[0] }).then(data => {
            listN.push({contract: f.fightContract, Staked: data})
          })
        })
        return listN
}

Comment: Yes, but what's the format of the data you fetch? Also, please provide the full code (including the `return` statement) of that component.